# Bayesian $\chi^2$ discrepancy

Tags: bayesian, validation

We define the $\chi^2$ discrepancy as $$T(y,\theta)=\sum_i\frac{(y_i-E(y_i|\theta))^2}{\mathrm{var}(y_i|\theta)}$$
(definition from Gelman). How do we apply this if $\theta$ is a random variable, and we have samples of it(but not the distribution)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is explained in [Gelman et al (1996)](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall09/cos597A/papers/GelmanMengStern1996.pdf) section 2.3 and 2.4.  The dependence of discrepancy statistics on $\theta$ is the key generalization over [Rubin's (1984)](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall11/cos597C/reading/Rubin1984.pdf) early writing on posterior predictive checks.  The posterior predictive p-value will integrate out the $\theta$ using simulations.  That's equation 9 in the linked to paper.  Specifically,

$p_b(y) = \int p(\chi^{2}_n ≥ \chi^2(y;\theta)p(\theta | H, y)d\theta.$

Given K simulations, $\theta_k$, calculate the discrepancy statistic for each and check whether it's more extreme than the known $\chi^2_n$ distribution.  The posterior predictive p-value is the average of these binary $K$ variables.

Comment: Thanks! I need a quick clarification; I am using a hiarchical model with some hyperparameters that are also random(and I have samples for corresponding to $\theta$. For $p(\theta|H,y)$, do I use these parameters as part of H? Also, what is a good $p_b$ value?

Comment: It depends on if those parameters enter the discrepancy statistic. In your case, you probably don't need to deal with them.  Uncertainty in the hyperparameters will be incorporated into uncertainty in $\theta$, so you'll be integrating over all the parameters.  The level 0.05 is "standard", following frequentist tradition, but don't get too hung up on $p_b$.  It's often better to perform graphical checks since the motivation is discovering ways to improve the model not hypothesis testing.